# How to assign arrays student's id with Boolean value in react js and if i clicked on button again back to boolean value for that particular student

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I called an API and the response is an array of students ids are there.

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Thorsten",
  "isClicked": false
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Daria",
  "isClicked": false
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Elset",
  "isClicked": false
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Wells",
  "isClicked": false
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "name": "Ashlin",
  "isClicked": false
}, {
  "id": 6,
  "name": "Wallache",
  "isClicked": false
}]
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Table extends Component {
   constructor(){
      super();     
      this.state = {
      };
      this.cancelRequest = this.deleteRecord.bind(this);
   } 

   deleteRecord(std_id) {
      alert(std_id);   
   }
  
   render() { 
       this.students.map((student,i) => {
     return (
     <tr>
      <td>student id</td>
      <td>student name</td>
      <td><button onclick={() =>this.deleteRecord(student.id)}>Delete</button></td>
     </tr> 
     )
    }); 
   }
}

export default Table;
```

Every 30 sec this API is hitting and get some new results. I mean some more extra record will come. But I want to assign all the id's with Boolean value false and there will be a button is there. If click on button for that particular id's Boolean value will goes to true.
Refer the below screen shot

[image]

Every time the page is refreshing, so new data is coming. again I want to assign the new student id with Boolean value false and if we click on delete button I want to make it as true for that particular id.

**How to solve this problem in react js?**

Comment: Why don't you add a `deleted` field to every Student object? It would be much cleaner.

Comment: We can't add at backend. there have some problem.

Comment: Let's say i added deleted field in every student object. then how to do?

Comment: 1- Every 30 secs, do you fetch new results only, or do you fetch all results including new results? 2- Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: fetching all results including new results?

Comment: I have updated my code. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can compound id.

Example:

```js
{
  "id": '1-0', //Here 0 means false, in similar fashion you can use 1 for true
  "name": "Thorsten"
}
```

Then only disadvantage of this approach is that you have to perform more computation than usual.

```js
var obj = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Thorsten",
  "isClicked": false
}

function serialize(obj, flag = false){
  obj.id = `${obj.id.toString().split('-')[0]}-${flag ? 1: 0}`; 
}
function deserialize(obj){
  return obj.id.toString().split('-')[1] == true; 
}
```

Comment: let's say one more field is there. like { "id" : 1, "name": "john", "isCancel": false} then what i need to do now

Comment: Please elaborate more!